# How to wire Emerson AC/DC Power Supply in USA? Came with a Chinese power cord

Tags: adapter, multiple

I'm trying to wire up this AC to DC converter and have never seen the connections that this thing came with.
The converter is an Emerson R48-3200.
The label shows AC input 200-250 Vac 18 A 50/60 Hz.
DC output is 48 V 3200 W.
It's the AC input side that is confusing to me and how to wire it up in a 120 V world here in the U.S.
There are 3 pins on the Emerson AC connector labeled as Pin1=Gnd  Pin2= N  Pin3= L.
The cord it came with has an SCED TP950P on one end that plugs into the back of the unit and on the other end of the power cord it has an connector labeled C3-10 10 A 250 V. The C3-10 seems to be a standard Chinese Type I plug but I can't find any adapter cables.
I have previously wired up a 240 V USA Nema 6-50R but it doesn't use a neutral and has only two Live connectors and a ground. I'm hoping to find the most economical way to wire this up. I could make an adapter but would need to find a source for these plugs, or I could cut the cord it came with in half- and make the connection from there, or **?**
I want it safe but I'm the only one going to be using it.

So how do I wire the 110 V wires from my panel to get 240 V and do I need a Neutral plus a ground?
Don't want to guess but do I join two hot wires together to L connection?

Comment: Photos of the plug and such would be helpful for identification.

Comment: Photos with dimensions- IIRC the South African plug closely resembles another but is much larger.

Comment: The cheapest and safest option that does not require an electrician to wire 240V plugs everywhere you want to use this supply is to replace the power supply with 120V version so it can be used with standard 120V plug.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE.  As noted in other comments, so photos of the equipment labels, and plugs would make it easier to give correct advise.

Answer (score 0):

C3-10 is a South African plug, I think.

In any case you can cut it off and wire it to something acceptable in North America such as a Hubbell twist-lock connector (industrial) or a dryer or stove plug (from a big box store).

Getting the 240VAC from your panel to the mating female connector (with appropriate breakers) would best be left to a qualified electrician, who can also check your plug wiring. There are two hots and a ground wire in North American residential power systems where 240VAC is concerned. The mains neutral would not be used.  The ground is not optional.